# Drywall installed over trim

Tags: drywall, trim

We had a contractor install a new window and he had to replace the drywall above the window. We have ceiling molding and we see that they covered part of the molding with the drywall. Any good way of correcting this?

Comment: Call the contractor back and have them fix it.

Comment: Some pictures will help also to show us what you mean exactly.

Comment: perhaps scrape chunks off first with a drywall knife or carpet knife, then sand with 60 or 100 grid, then 150 or 200 grit, keeping the shape of the molding